# Unable to identify the element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I can able to identify the element upto - span id="trayCover_page0ivu0"

After that i 'm not able to identify pls help.

I have to click the below line.

```
<a class="SItreeText" href="#" style="word-wrap: normal; white-space: nowrap;"></a>
```

Please let me know any thing is executed to hide the element in -

```
pageSupport._setHtmlbIds("page0ivu0","Tray4b6ce4ad… script
```

I tried with below code which is not working:

```
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@style='word-wrap: normal; white-space: nowrap;']"));
        // driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='SItreeText']")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".SItreeText")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.linkText("Ford CRM Centre")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/table/tbody[2]/tr[2]/td[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/a")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#DetailedNavigationTree")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '#')]")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='SItreeText']")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#DetailedNavigationTree/navurl.SItreeText")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '#')]")).click();
        //driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/table/tbody[2]/tr[2]/td[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/a")));
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Ford CRM Centre')]")).click();
        //WebElement WE = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='DetailedNavigationTree']"));
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#DetailedNavigationTree:state"));

<a class="SItreeText" href="#" style="word-wrap: normal; white-space: nowrap;"></a>
```

**Html Code:**

```
<div id="nav_container_div" class="nav" style="">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="WIDTH: 100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="trayCover_page0ivu0" style="margin:0;padding:0">
                        <script>

                            pageSupport._setHtmlbIds("page0ivu0","Tray4b6ce4ad…

                        </script>
                        <input id="Tray4b6ce4ad_es" type="hidden" value="false" name="Tray4b6ce4ad_es"></input>
                        <table id="Tray4b6ce4ad" class="urTrcWhlHdr" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;" onkeydown="sapUrMapi_Tray_keydown('Tray4b6ce4ad',event);" st="+" ct="TY" cols="1">
                            <tbody></tbody>
                            <tbody id="Tray4b6ce4ad-tbd">
                                <tr class="urTrcSpcRowHdContTrn"></tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="urTrcBdyNotchTrn"></td>
                                    <td class="urTrcSpcVertLftMidTrn"></td>
                                    <td class="urTrcBodyHdr urTrcBodyBdrHdr" valign="top">
                                        <div class="urTrcBodyHdr urTrcBodyHdrBdr urTrcBodyHdrPd">
                                            <div id="Tray4b6ce4ad-bd">
                                                <!--

                                                 EPCF: Component com.sap.portal.navigation.detaile…

                                                -->
                                                <div id="UiServiceToServerDIV" style="{display:none}"></div>
                                                <script></script>
                                                <span id="DetailedNavigationTree:sel" class="SItreeSelColor" style="display:none"></span>
                                                <span id="DetailedNavigationTree:selmark" class="SItreeSelColorMarked" style="display:none"></span>
                                                <div id="DetailedNavigationTree" class="SItree">
                                                    <div style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 10px; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                        <img src="/irj/portalapps/com.sap.portal.design.portaldesigndata/theme…portal/ford_theme/nav/treeview/ico12_treeleaf.gif?7.0.24.1.6"></img>
                                                        <img id="DetailedNavigationTree/navurl://cd82866421cb92cf96c103eb19061574" src="/irj/portalapps/com.sap.portal.design.portaldesigndata/themes/portal/ford_theme/common/1x1.gif?7.0.24.1.6"></img>
                                                        <a class="SItreeText" href="#" style="word-wrap: normal; white-space: nowrap;"></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input id="DetailedNavigationTree:state" type="HIDDEN" name="DetailedNavigationTree"></input>
                                                </div>
```

Comment: Try with By.cssSelector("#DetailedNavigationTree a.SItreeText")

Comment: Thank you very much Santhoshsarma..... It working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below locators also

```
By.cssSelector("#DetailedNavigationTree a.SItreeText")

By.cssSelector("#DetailedNavigationTree>div>a.SItreeText")

By.cssSelector("table[id*='Tray'] div[id*='Tray'] div#DetailedNavigationTree a")

By.cssSelector("table[id*='Tray'] div[id*='Tray'] div#DetailedNavigationTree>div>a")
```